# How can I speed up the model.test() function of Fasttext Python API?

Tags: performance, nlp, classification, fasttext

I'm training and testing a Fasttext classification model using the [package's Python API](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html). I expected the model training (using the model.train_supervised() function) to be slower than the model testing (using the model.text() function).

However, I see model testing takes about the same time (25min in my case) as model training.

Is this because the model.test() function is single-threaded, while training is multi-threaded? Is there a way to speed up the testing?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with fasttext, but this is definitely not a common situation, and it is unlikely that only training is multi-threaded. Please provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).